# std::array member in template class vs vector

Tags: c++

I have a class `A` that needs to hold a container member `generators` with `N` elements. This `N` is typically small, of the order of 1 -- 100 objects in most applications and the contained members are used intensively in the application. Moreover, `N` is known at compile time.  Now I'm faced with a design choice of having the member being an array as in

```cpp
template <unsigned int N>
class A {
  private:
    std::array<Generators, N> generators;
  public:
    A() = default;
     ...  // do something with N
};
```

Or take `N` as a parameter in the constructor and use a `std::vector` as in

```
class A {
  private:
    std::vector<Generators> generators;
  public:
    A(unsigned int N) // do something with N
    ...
};
```

The problem with the template solution is that it leads to large header files and awkward inclusions of circularly dependent template classes that need to be therefore defined in the same header (in this case `A` depends on `Generator` and viceversa).

What is the normal choice here? Is there any significant performance penalty in switching to vectors instead?

Comment: I would expect performance to be similar as long as you `generators.reserve(N)` in your constructor.  (Though it's worth considering potential cache implications - I believe `std::array`'s storage can be allocated on the stack, whereas `std::vector` must use the heap).  Also there may be potential optimizations and static checks you can apply in your implementation if `N` is known at compile-time.

Comment: I've seen cppcon benchmarks showing minimal performance difference between vector and array when implemented correctly. For me, the difference comes down to what i want to communicate in the code. If i use the array, the fixed length is a physical constraint that should convey a meaningful reason for such bound. If i use a vector, the class is describing a degree of freedom tht should be reflected by the functionality of the class.

Comment: The real relevant question is: should N be known to the *user* of the class? Does it *matter* for the user? If not, don’t make it part of the interface: don’t burden users with irrelevant implementation details. (Even so you might still want to use `std::array…` *inside* the class, but type-erase it. Though in that case I’d be tempted to accept that a `std::vector` can substitute for a size-type-erased `std::array` just fine and with minimal overhead.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because N is known at compile time and not really large I'd prefer the template version.

You don't need to include other types in your header. You could make "Generator" a template-parameter, too.

You coulde write:

```cpp
//A.h

#pragma once

#include <array>

class Generator;

template <
   unsigned int N, 
   typename Generator = ::Generator
>
class A {
  private:
    std::array<Generator, N> generators;
  public:
    A() = default;
};
```

and

```cpp
//something.cpp
#include "a.h"

class Generator {

};


int main(){
    A<10> a10;
}
```

Comment: In addition you could consider making "A" an so called "aggregate" -> removing the constructor of "A", and marking "generators" as public.
Look at "std::array".

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately the actual constructor of `A` is rather involved. I'll test the approach of this answer and   accept it. My `Generators` themselves are a template that depend on `A` but this should work anyway